# What is the difference between a list with anything ([_]) and anything (_)

Tags: list, prolog

I was trying to accomplish the following, if I have two lists, L1 and L2, I wanted that the result (R) to be the "subtraction" of L2 from L1.

Example:

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [2,3,4,5]

R = [1]
```

I WAS able to accomplish this but I can't tell what is the difference between `_` and `[_]`.

If I do this:

```
diferencia([],_,[]).
diferencia([X|Tail],L2,R):-
    member(X,L2),
    diferencia(Tail,L2,R).
diferencia([X|Tail],L2,[X|R]):-
    not(member(X,L2)),
    diferencia(Tail,L2,R).
```

It works, if I do this, it gives me false:

```
diferencia([],[_],[]).
diferencia([X|Tail],L2,R):-
    member(X,L2),
    diferencia(Tail,L2,R).
diferencia([X|Tail],L2,[X|R]):-
    not(member(X,L2)),
    diferencia(Tail,L2,R).
```

I would assume a list containing anything `[_]` should work since L2 will always be a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, `_` matches one variable and one variable only. Here, you'd want it to match `2, 3, 4, 5` (the four variables). It can't. It can only match `[2, 3, 4, 5]` (the list). You'd have to write `[_|_]` so that the head and the tail are matched (`[2|[3, 4, 5]]`)

Or `[_, _, _, _, _, _, ...]` with the number of `_` being the exact number of items in your list so that every single element is properly matched with an anonymous variable.

The basic thing to remember is that `_` is just a normal variable. If you have troubles remembering it, just explicit names, like `_Head` or `_Accumulator`, so that you do realize when you write your code that the thing you manipulate is actually a variable, only you do not care about it (variable starting with a `_` won't produce a singleton variable warning, in swi-pl at least, so they're usable instead of `_` for a better overall clarity).

**Edit** : one other way to say it is that in your title, you think `_` is anything. But anything can be nothing, and anything can be many things. `_` can only be one thing. That's why it doesn't work : ]

Comment: Variable called `_` is not really a normal variable. If you have two variables called `_`, they won't unify, they are two different variables.

Comment: normal variable was here used to imply that the anonymous variables cannot do things a regular variable can't do when it comes to match patterns. The fact that two anonymous variables don't necessarily unify was shown anyway in the examples above. Thanks for clarifying anyway!

Answer (score 4):

`_` is anything... foo, [1,2], bar(42,foo[2,3,7]) etc
`[_]` is a list that has exactly one element that could be anything

in your example if L2 has more than one elements (or is the empty list) then it won't match with `[_]`